# Redirect to a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for a way to open a Chrome extension from URL, in HTML and Javascript.
Something like redirect to `chrome://<extension-id>` (which doesn't work on the last version of Chrome).

Is it possible?

Can I retrieve all the extensions installed on Chrome (user side)?

In this case I would be able to get the ID of the application, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I've just solved in this way:

```
window.location = chrome.extension.getURL('index.html');
```

As I'm developing a Chrome extension, this code automatically redirect to the main page of the extension (it requires a proper `manifest.json` file).